# Can/should I use rapid rise yeast for longer proofing?

Tags: baking, yeast

More generally, what are the limitations of rapid rise yeast compared to other types of yeast?

Answer (score 3):

Rapid rise yeast has enhancers added to make the yeast more active and lower the amount of time needed to proof the dough.

I wouldn't use it if I wanted a longer proofing time because I think the dough would rise too far wouldn't result in a good crumb or flavor.  That being said I think you could use rapid rise yeast with a longer proofing time.  Maybe you would want the larger volume of dough and other effects.